# Why don't we see the big bang?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, observable-universe

excuse my understanding, my brain is melting.

So I understand that pictures of far away objects is like viewing the past.
and I think I pretty much get that the big bang was in every direction since it is the expansion of space.
If also the big bang was bright, then should we not see it in the background of all the pictures from JWST?

Comment: We do see the Big Bang. That's what the [cosmic microwave background radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) is. It's just not as spectacular as you'd hoped :-)

Comment: Search term: cosmic microwave background.

Comment: Big Bang is not the cmb nor even close.

Comment: have a look  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/planck.html#c1

Comment: Congratulations for accidentally discovering the cosmic microwave background!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the big bang was initially so hot, it was also opaque to light. The universe did not cool down enough to become transparent to light until an event called *recombination*, which took place about 370,000 years after the Big Bang. This means we can't see (in "lookback time") earlier than that.

The radiation which bathed the universe at recombination time has since been stretched out in wavelength as the universe expanded and now resides in the microwave band of electromagnetic radiation. We call that "fossil radiation" the *cosmic microwave background* or CMB. This "afterglow" of the big bang is coming at us from all directions and its origin is *behind* all the most distant galaxies we can see today.

Neutrinos were generated in copious amounts before recombination, which means there are fossil neutrinos coming at us from times *earlier than recombination*. If we had some way to make images of that neutrino bath, we could then see farther back in time- but alas, even the best neutrino detectors we currently have are not sensitive enough to detect them.

Comment: "even the best neutrino detectors we currently have are not sensitive enough to detect them"  Does this include Ice Cube?

Comment: Yes. It is unlikely that we will ever develop a neutrino imaging device which could do that. Physics conspires against us.

Comment: I see (via Wikipedia) that neutrinos oscillate, and are fermions, but, although oscillation would give some size to even the point-like particles required by 1915's GR, the fact of their being fermions would give them a measurable size (a few orders of magnitude greater than the Planck length) in the newer of Einstein's theories of gravity (1929's Einstein-Cartan Theory), which (to the layperson that is myself) might consequently seem advantageous to anyone trying to figure out why the Big Bang could not be seen until after the delay whose origin the OP had been trying to understand.

Comment: @Edouard,neutrinos are point-like and lack internal structure.

Comment: Yes; I'd visualized their oscillations as being disappearances and reappearances, each at faintly different locations, of the "point" of whichever one of them would be under examination (for which I suppose we lack the necessary magnification energy, or maybe something more crass, like the lack of budget money for construction of the magnifying devices).  I'm guessing you're feeling that some minimal size of fermions is a major flaw in ECT, which it may be, at least if the limits on our magnification capabilities are more physical than fiscal.

Comment: I haven't been able to find out how Cartan arrived at his criterion for the spatial expanse of fermions:  PSE's an English-language site (which still lacks a tag for ECT), & I'd imagine it's more of an eastern theory, backwatered after Einstein sorta lost the EPR debate.

Comment: I do not know anything about ECT, this is the first time in my life I have seen it cited.

Comment: That's very interesting, as the torsion-based cosmological model of the physicist Nikodem Poplawski (whose numerous 2010-2021 preprints on it can be found by his name on Cornell University's Arxiv website) has been more widely-received in the U.S. than in Cartan's native France (where both of his sons have followed in his footsteps as major mathematicians):  It was literally yesterday that I (a retired interpreter) first found a Youtube version of it on a Franco-German site.  As his model allow past-eternality, I guess the U.S. has more of a "front" between science & fundamentalist religion.

Comment: For readers who deal with students, the French/German subtitled/sound Youtube piece is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liMycl-WioQ  .